# Angular JS filters UNIX time, thinks it's 1970, otherwise fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angularjs-directive

I'm using the following filter

```
{{ "791877600"|date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

It should be 1995-02-04. The actual result is 1970-01-09

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're using seconds, should be milliseconds like

```
{{ "7918776000000"|date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use milliseconds:

```
{{ "791877600" * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```